# How to Detect Window On Minimize/Maximize Event in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to catch the event when a browser window is minimized/maximized using Google Chrome Extensions. How to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

To know whether a given window is minimized / maximized, just use [`chrome.windows.get`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-get):

```js
// assume windowId is given
chrome.windows.get(windowId, function(chromeWindow) {
    // "normal", "minimized", "maximized" or "fullscreen"
    alert('Window is ' + chromeWindow.state);
});
```

There's no event that tells you that a window is minimized / maximized. However, you can get notified of window focus changes via [`chrome.windows.onFocusChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onFocusChanged). This event provides an ID which can be used in the method shown at the top of my answer. Note that it may occasionally be called with "-1" ([`chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#property-WINDOW_ID_NONE)). In this case, just assume that the window is minimized.

```js
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    if (windowId === -1) {
         // Assume minimized
    } else {
        chrome.windows.get(windowId, function(chromeWindow) {
            if (chromeWindow.state === "minimized") {
                // Window is minimized
            } else {
                // Window is not minimized (maximized, fullscreen or normal)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: if (windowId === -1) ... Why the API sometimes returns windowsId with value -1 ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir `-1` is the constant `WINDOW_ID_NONE`. This windowId indicates that there's no focused window. Hence I suggested to assume that the window is minimized.

Comment: Did not work this solution. Help me to detect minimize browser window event