# chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener firing with windowId= -1 after opening context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to fetch all events (maximized, maximize etc). I have a suitable code for this from this link [How to Detect Window On Minimize/Maximize Event in Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785321/how-to-detect-window-on-minimize-maximize-event-in-chrome-extension).

The problem is when I open the context menu (right click) and then left click on the window it is firing with windowId = -1, but it is focused on the window. It shouldn't fire with windowId = -1. So I couldn't find the exact minimize/maximize event after opening context-menu.

My code is :

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    if (windowId === -1) {
         // Assume minimized
         console.log("minimized",windowId);
    } else {
        chrome.windows.get(windowId, function(chromeWindow) {
            if (chromeWindow.state === "minimized") {
                console.log("minimized");
            } else {
                console.log("maximized");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Please help me in this,thank you.

Comment: there is a bug in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449492 window shouldn't lose focus on context menu

Comment: Thank you for your information @WolfWar . Is there no way out to get proper minimize/maximize event without this?

Comment: no, not that I know of, sry