# chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener not firing on tab switching

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to fetch all events (maximized, maximize etc). I have a suitable code for this from this link [How to Detect Window On Minimize/Maximize Event in Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785321/how-to-detect-window-on-minimize-maximize-event-in-chrome-extension).

But the problem when switch tab (using alt+tab) window.chrome.onFocusChanged listener is not firing.

My code :

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    console.log("focus change", windowId);    
});
```

Is there a solution for this or... it is a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug which was already posted at the [Chrome Bug Tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=387377&thanks=387377&ts=1403370788) back in 2014. Unfortunately, it received little to no attention. No news if it will be fixed in milestone iterations in the near future either.

Comment: really to sorry to hear that :( . I am stuck in a bad situation for this. Anyway thank you for this info.